# Django Models comparison

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm beginning with Django and I have a Civil Status project.
I created my first models.py in order to get a Form, but I had some advices in order to normalize my database.

I made this process and I would like to know what do you think about this new restructuration.

My old models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .countries import CHOIX_PAYS # Importation de la liste des pays
from .sexe import CHOIX_SEXE # Importation de la liste des sexes 

# Create my Form model BirthCertificate

class BirthCertificate(models.Model) :

    nom = models.CharField('Nom', max_length=30, null=False)   # Lastname
    prenom = models.CharField('Prénom', max_length=30, null = False)   # Firstname
    sexe = models.CharField('Sexe', max_length=1, choices = CHOIX_SEXE)  # Choice between 'M' or 'F'
    birthday = models.DateField('Date de naissance', null=False)
    birthhour = models.TimeField('heure de naissance', null=False)
    birthcity = models.CharField('Ville de naissance', max_length = 30, null=False)
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    nom_pere = models.CharField('Nom père', max_length=30, null=False)
    prenom_pere = models.CharField('Prénom père', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthday_pere = models.DateField('Date de naissance du père', null=False)
    birthcity_pere = models.CharField('Ville de naissance du père', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthcountry_pere = models.CharField('Pays de naissance du père', max_length=2, choices= CHOIX_PAYS)
    job_pere = models.CharField('Profession du père', max_length=30, null=False)
    adress_pere = models.CharField('Adresse du père', max_length=40, null=False)
    ville_pere = models.CharField('Ville du père', max_length=30, null=False)
    zip_pere = models.IntegerField('Code Postal du père', null=False)
    pays_pere = models.CharField('Pays du père', max_length=2, choices= CHOIX_PAYS)

    nom_mere = models.CharField('Nom mère', max_length=30, null=False)
    prenom_mere = models.CharField('Prénom mère', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthday_mere = models.DateField('Date de naissance de la mère', null=False)
    birthcity_mere = models.CharField('Ville de naissance de la mère', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthcountry_mere = models.CharField('Pays de naissance de la mère', max_length=2, choices= CHOIX_PAYS)
    job_mere = models.CharField('Profession de la mère', max_length=30, null=False)
    adress_mere = models.CharField('Adresse de la mère', max_length=40, null=False)
    ville_mere = models.CharField('Ville de la mère', max_length=30, null=False)
    zip_mere = models.IntegerField('Code Postal de la mère', null=False)
    pays_mere = models.CharField('Pays de la mère', max_length=2, choices= CHOIX_PAYS)

    nom_temoin1 = models.CharField('Nom témoin n°1', max_length=30, null=False)
    prenom_temoin1 = models.CharField('Prénom témoin n°1', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthday_temoin1 = models.DateField('Date de naissance du témoin n°1', null=False)
    birthcity_temoin1 = models.CharField('Ville de naissance du témoin n°1', max_length=30, null=False)

    nom_temoin2 = models.CharField('Nom témoin n°2', max_length=30, null=False)
    prenom_temoin2 = models.CharField('Prénom témoin n°2', max_length=30, null=False)
    birthday_temoin2 = models.DateField('Date de naissance du témoin n°2', null=False)
    birthcity_temoin2 = models.CharField('Ville de naissance du témoin n°2', max_length=30, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

And my new models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Country(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False) # Example : 'FR' - 'US' 
    pays = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False) # Example : 'France' - 'Etats-Unis'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Sexe(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=False) # Example : 'M' or 'F'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=False) # Example : 'Mâle' or 'Femelle'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Civility(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False) # 'Mr' - 'Mlle' - 'Mme' - ..
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False) # 'Monsieur' - 'Mademoiselle' - ..

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Parent1(models.Model):

    civility = models.ForeignKey(Civility)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    sexe = models.ForeignKey(Sexe)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False)
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    zip = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname

class Parent2(models.Model):

    civility = models.ForeignKey(Civility)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    sexe = models.ForeignKey(Sexe)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False)
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    zip = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname

class BirthCertificate(models.Model):

    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False) 
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    sexe = models.ForeignKey(Sexe)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False)
    birthhour = models.TimeField(null=False)
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    birthcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Parent1)
    parent2 = models.ForeignKey(Parent2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname
```

Is it better ? maybe a faster process ? (#DaftPunkSong).
Do you have some advices yet ?

Thank you

Comment: [codereview.se] (Please read their guidelines first though before posting)

Comment: Quick observation though, `Parent1/2` should probably just be a single parent class with BirthCertificate having a ManyToManyRelationship, A parent can have multiple children and a birth certificate can have multiple (or even a single parent which you don't account for) parents.

Comment: [3 parent birth certificate](https://www.simplycertificate.co.uk/blog/three-parent-birth-certificates-what-are-they)

Comment: @Sayse Thank you to your comment. I didn't know this section `Code Review`. So I will put my script and wait for advices. I take care yours ;)